# Build Spacy NER Loop for Dataframe

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

currently I want to perform spacy NER on all text files in my directory and have as output "Number of NER/Total Words in Text". I dont know how to automate it. Currently I use:

```
def read_txt_files(PATH:str):
    
    results = defaultdict(list)
    for file in Path(PATH).iterdir():
        with open(file, "rt",newline='', encoding="utf8") as file_open:
            results["file_num"].append(file.name)
            results["text"].append(file_open.read().replace('\n'," "))
    df = pd.DataFrame(results)
    
    return df
def Specificity(input_data: pd.Series):
    specificity = [0]*len(input_data)
    
    for i in tqdm(range(len(input_data)), desc = 'Get the Specificity'):
        specificity[i] = len((ner(input_data[i])).ents)/len((input_data[i]))
    
    #[len(ner(data[i]).ents)/len(data[i]) for i in tqdm(range(len(data)))]
    
    return specificity
```

But it somehow just shows the wrong values for specificity, much lower than it should be.

When I perform NER on a single text file it looks like this:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
text = open(r"mydirectory", 'r',encoding='utf-8').read()
parsed_text = nlp(text)
named_entities = parsed_text.ents
num_words = len ([ token
    for token in parsed_text
    if not token . is_punct ])
num_entities = len ( named_entities )
specificity_score = num_entities/num_words
```

Is there a way to "switch" both specificity measures and let the "second" code perform?

Answer (score 0):

As the `Pandas` and `SpaCy` already have provided handy functions I tried to implement your solution in a more legible format. The obvious problem is that `nlp(text)` is determined two times which is a burden!

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['This is a test from USA', 'Ronaldo missed the WC']})
get_spec = lambda text:len(nlp(text).ents)/len([token for token in nlp(text) if not token.is_punct])
df['spec'] = df['text'].apply(get_spec)
print(df)
```

output:

```
                      text      spec
0  This is a test from USA  0.166667
1    Ronaldo missed the WC  0.250000
```